# what is the group $\langle a,b,c,d,e\mid cde=1\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

As title, I'm doing a problem in algeraic topology, and met this  group, I need to figure out what it is. I met similar group such as $\langle a,b,c\mid c=1\rangle $ and $\langle a,b,c,d\mid cd=1\rangle$, I believe these two are both free groups, but not sure what happens when adding another generator.

Comment: Your relation allows you to eliminate generator $e$ as product $e=(Cd)^-1$, so the group is free on a,b,c,d. The general mechanism for such tricks goes under the name of Tietze transformations.

Comment: I guess you can write a formal answer and I will accept it :) @ahuplke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by ahulpke, all you can say is that your group is a free group in 4 generators say $a,b,c,d$ and the fifth element namely $e$ can be written as a word in the form : $e=d^{-1}c^{-1}$ . In this case drawing a Cayley graph is easy:

[image]